# Show that two random variables are equal in distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, brownian-motion

I found this exercise at the end of a chapter about Brownian motion. Let $(X_j)_{j=1}^{2^M}$ be independent standard Gaussian random variables, where $M$ is a integer. Define $B_k:=2^{\frac{-M}{2}}\sqrt{T}\sum_{j=1}^kX_j$, where $0<T\in\mathbb{R}$. Furthermore let $(W_{k2^{-M}T})_{k=1}^{2^M}$ be a Brownian motion. Then $(W_{k2^{-M}T})_{k=1}^{2^M}=(B_k)_{k=1}^{2^M}$ in distribution. There is a hint: I should find a matrix $A$, which transform the $(X_k)_{k=1}^{2^M}$ into $(B_k)_{k=1}^{2^M}$.

So far I did the following:

For the matrix $2^{\frac{-M}{2}}\sqrt{T}A$ I've chosen: $$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \cdots \\
1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots& 0 \\
1 & \cdots  & \cdots & 1
\end{pmatrix}
  $$

Then clearly $2^{\frac{-M}{2}}\sqrt{T}AX=B$, seen as vectors. Hence I know that $B$ is normal distributed with mean $0$ and covariance matrix $A\cdot \mathrm{Id}\cdot A^T$. For the product $A\cdot A^T$ I got:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots \\
1 & 2 & 2 & \cdots \\
\vdots & 2 & 3&3&\cdots  \\
\vdots & 2 & 3 & 4&  \cdots\\
\vdots &  \vdots&\vdots&\vdots
\end{pmatrix}
  $$
with the factor $2^{-M}T$ in front. Clearly $(W_{k2^{-M}T})_{k=1}^{2^M}$ has expectation zero and is normally distributed. But I do not see why the covariance matrices are the same. I hope someone could help me. Thanks in advance.

hulik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The covariance matrices are the same. Indeed, if $j\leq k$, then 
\begin{align}\operatorname{Cov}(W_{k2^{-m}T},W_{j2^{-m}T})&=\operatorname{Cov}(W_{k2^{-m}T}-W_{j2^{—m}},W_{j2^{-m}T})+\operatorname{Cov}(W_{j2^{-m}T},W_{j2^{-m}T})\\
&=\operatorname{Cov}(W_{j2^{-m}T},W_{j2^{-m}T})\\
&=j2^{-m}T\\
&=2^{-m}T\min\{j,k\},
\end{align}
which is exactly what was obtained.